# How to select columns based on true/false condition in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to select columns where the following is true.

```
mask = df.select_dtypes(include = ['object']).apply(pd.Series.nunique) > 100

rbc      False
pc       False
pcc      False
ba       False
htn      False
dm       False
cad      False
appet    False
pe       False
ane      False
class    False
lev_a     True
lev_b     True
l_x      False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: What is your pandas version?

Answer (score 2):

Use the result as a boolean mask

```
df.loc[:, mask]
```

Comment: It doesn't work...Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match

Comment: Sorry, try that

Comment: still...I try to use a for loop doesn't work either
lis=[]
for i in h:
    if h[i] == True:
        lis.append[i]
lis

Comment: Well, I could try to create a sample data set that I think matches what you have... or, you could provide sample data for me so I don't have to guess.  That way, I have an immediate idea of whether or not what I'm doing is working.

Comment: I think this will work if all columns are "object" (?).  Btw, I edited the question to define the code as "mask" in case you want to re-write your answer as `df.loc[:,mask]` I thought about editing myself but generally am conservative about editing other people's code.

Comment: I've had some people that edit my posts that do mess it up.  However, I trust you.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is likely that the number of rows in your mask is different than the number of columns in your original dataframe (assuming your columns are a mix of object and non-object).

Given your set up, this should return the columns satisfying your criterion (which you can then use as an input for `loc[]`):

```
mask.index[mask]
```

You want to say `mask.index` here rather than `mask.columns` because your mask is a pandas series where the index consists of the columns in your original dataframe `df`.

Here's a more complete example with sample data (in your future questions please provide your own sample data and you'll generally get more and better answers):

```
df = pd.DataFrame( np.random.choice(list('abcde'),[10,5]), 
                          columns=list('ABCDE'))

mask = df.select_dtypes(include=['object']).apply(pd.Series.nunique) > 4

mask.index[mask]
```

Result:

```
Index(['B', 'C'], dtype='object')
```